# How not count blank spaces in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, regex, string, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I have this line

```
StringTokenizer tk=new StringTokenizer (b=10," =",true);
```

my output is

```
b
=
10
```

and this perfect but again if my line is this

```
StringTokenizer tk=new StringTokenizer (DEFI b=10," =",true);
```

And my output is

```
DEFI

b
=
10
```

I don't wanna include that empty o white space in the ST, How can I avoid including the white space cause I want this kind of output

```
DEFI
b
=
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, I suggest using String.split() method:

```
String[] tokens = "DEFI b=10".split("(\\s|(?=\\=)|(?<=\\=))");
```

Answer (score 2):

String tokenizer contrusts a string tokenizer from a specified string: (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

```
      public StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean returnDelims)
```

As your parameters you have a a object declaration declaring an int value, a delim which is an equal sign and delim flag which is true (which returns the delim character as a token)

Maybe you should refactor your String tokenizer instance to the following:

```
     String b = "DDEFI-b-=-10"; //Create the string to be evaluated

     String delim = "-"; //Create a delim which serves as a separator
```

(Defining the string as "DEFI-b-=-10" - will provide the correct spacing with your delim)

```
     StringTokenizer tk= new StringTokenizer (b, delim);

    /* Loop through the elements printing out the specified string */

     while(tk.hasMoreElements()) {
          System.out.println(tk.nextToken());
       }



     //Result
     DEFI
     b
     =
     10
```

Comment: so, I need put "-" in every string?

Comment: It can be any character .. the delim just represents the separator between your string